# Does "unfounded" have the connotation of "not fair"?

Tags: word-meaning, connotations

Does "unfounded" refer rather to the lack of arguments for a statement or their irrelevantness?

Comment: You could determine this by looking the word up in a couple of dictionaries. Basic questions of meaning are off-topic.  **unfounded allegations** are unfair *because* they're unfounded.

Comment: I do not understand your last question about a name.  To be unfounded is to have no basis in fact.  How can a *name* be unfounded?  It makes no assertion.  Are you referring to "calling someone a name", like "You cheater!"?

Comment: Yes, when you call someone a name, as in *You cheater!* you're stating that they have cheated. That is an assertion, and as an assertion it can have a basis in fact, or not.  If it has no basis in fact, you can reply, "That remark was unfounded".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Ok, so that is not what I meant. What if there is evidence for something but the term is inappropriate? Like calling an entepreuner a *thief* if they registered their enterprise in a low-tax country (it's legal). Or calling someone a rapist for touching someone, even though it has been caught on camera.

Comment: Calling someone a liar is to say that they have knowingly told a falsehood.   If a person has relied on outdated, incorrect information, and was in possession of more up-to-date correct information at the time, then they have perpetrated a falsehood.  The critical point is that they knowingly convey false information.

Comment: @Bilkokuya - The fact that there is a discussion like this in the comments suggests the OP should have at least looked up the word in a couple dictionaries, pasted their favorite definition in the question, and then used that as a foundation for the rest of the question. Then all this could have been avoided, and there's a good chance the question would have attracted more upvotes than downvotes and comments. This question is vague and ought to be edited. (If it gets edited and clarified, it can be reopened.)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer the question from the perspective of how to use the word **unfounded** in a sentence. *What  can be said to be unfounded?*

Following up on a productive distinction made in this comment:

> Ok, so that is not what I meant. What if there is evidence for
>   something but the term is inappropriate? Like calling an entepreuner a
>   thief if they registered their enterprise in a low-tax country (it's
>   legal). Or calling someone a rapist for touching someone, even though
>   it has been caught on camera.

The names themselves, the names *per se*, are not able to be unfounded, nor is the act of name-calling itself able to be unfounded. Rather the *underlying claim or assertion* will either have a basis in fact or be unfounded.

So it would be awkward to say *Calling me a liar is unfounded*. Calling me a liar is *unwarranted* or *unjustified*.  It would be better to say *Your **claim** that I'm a liar is unfounded.*  or *That **remark** was unfounded*. The assertion itself is what has, or does not have, a basis in fact. The *act* of making the assertion is not itself able to be factual.

But in conversation you could retort:

> "Liar" is unfounded!

because the intended (elliptical) meaning is "the allegation that I'm a liar...".

P.S. If the question is *Can an exaggeration be "unfounded"?* --well, yes, it can be, or at least the kernel assertion can be, because an exaggeration contains an assertion.

P.P.S. **unfounded** does not mean "having an *insufficient* basis in fact".

Answer (score 1):

[Unfounded](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unfounded) has two (similar) meanings:

> *(adjective)*
>   1. (of ideas, allegations, etc) baseless; groundless
>   2. not yet founded or established

---

As such, it can be used to describe statements that are either not based on facts and evidence (1), or statements relating to an idea that is not well established (2).

---

For definition (1), this means statements such as:

*"The sky is made of soup"* could be described as unfounded - as there is no evidence of this, and it's not based on factual evidence.

This is fairly straight forward - any statement that either hasn't got enough evidence to be disproven, or any statement whose evidence can be directly refuted - may be described as "unfounded".

---

For definition (2), this relates more to your question about names.

*"PoliticianA is a thief"* when referring to them avoiding tax (and not actual criminal theft), may be considered "unfounded" if there is no well established norm for considering tax evasion similar to theft.

Perhaps more clearly, *"your dog is evil"*, may be considered an unfounded belief - even if there is evidence for it hurting people - as there is no well established basis that dogs have a moral compass (and therefore cannot be good or evil).

---

On a site note, when it comes to the difference between having unfounded beliefs and being a liar. Most people will consider a liar somebody who actively tries to decieve. As such, if the person was not relying on unfounded statements on purpose - it would generally be considered inappropriate to call them a liar.

*(The belief that the person is a liar, may itself be considered unfounded - if there is no evidence they made those statements knowingly, or if they are otherwise of good character and so the idea of them being a liar is not well established)*